# Can I live in Europe if I have a full-remote job that will stay remote after Covid?

Tags: europe

My job has always been remote, even before Covid. Would it be possible to live in Europe on a non-work visa and remotely work my normal job in America?

Comment: Europe is rather diverse. You need to specify which countries and whether you would stay in one or travel around.

Comment: Working remotely is still working. You would most likely need a work visa, you employer would have to pay local social contributions and taxes, you would have to be registered with tax authorities and file tax returns and/or pay taxes, etc. You work contract would be subject to local laws and regulations. This can be mightily difficult and complex for a company in the US with no presence in your country of residence.

Comment: You would also need permission from your employer to work abroad, as it can have tax consequences for them in the other country.

Comment: It would not have tax implications for the company - it would have tax implications for the individual. The individual would need a work permit in the country where they are working, to allow them to pay tax there.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of work, residing in any country typically requires a special visa authorizing an indefinite long stay. Typically it's based on family ties, investment or work with the implicit wish of the lawmakers of allowing such for the sakes of taxes.

The only exception would be Svalbard https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/45131/4188

In the same thread, https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89602/4188 points out that Canada allows you to work remotely during a visit, Americans can typically stay for six months in Canada.

Also, still the same thread, Barbados just launched a program tailored for you. https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158462/4188

Comment: +1 for Svalbard :)

Answer (score 0):

One addition to chx’s answer.  During COVID, most of the European countries have implemented travel restrictions, where you are not allowed to enter the country unless you have a long-term residence permit from that country.  As is, the rules for living in a country without a Visa are 90/180: so after 90 days, you are not allowed to stay in the same country, and must cross into a different country.  This will be a problem if you do not have rights to enter that country.

That being said, if you restrict yourself to countries which do not have entry restrictions (e.g. Ukraine), and follow the 90/180 rule, then yes, you are allowed to do this.

Source: myself in the same situation.

Comment: There is also the issue with work permits. If you are working in a country (even if you are remote-working for a company in a different country), you are required to pay taxes in that country. This means that you need permission to work there, and usually need a work permit (depending on the visa). Whether you see this as "fair" or not, it is still usually a legal requirement.

Comment: This is country dependent. Canada doesn't require this.

Comment: Canada doesn’t require foreign citizens to get a work permit in order for them to work in Canada?